# Como evitar que o Django localize IDs no template?

Tags: python, django, l10n, localização

Eu estou usando `Django 1.4` com localização (L10N) ativada, o que faz com que os valores numéricos no template sejam formatados: `1.234,56`. O problema é que toda vez que eu coloco um `ID` no template, por exemplo:

```python
data-id="{{ form.instance.id }}"
```

Ele é renderizado como:

```python
data-id="1.234"
```

Obviamente que se esse `ID` vai para um `request ajax`, o `ID` não é encontrado na base, porque não é um valor `int` válido. Eu **posso evitar** esse comportamente utilizando `|safe` ou `|unlocalize`, porém em alguns lugares, por exemplo no `admin`, eu não tenho esse acesso (seria necessário alterar o Django), por exemplo:

```python
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}{{ original.pk }}">{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}</a>
```

É possível fazer o Django não localizar IDs de maneira generalizada?

Comment: É possível usar templates customizados para o admin, sem editar o APP admin do Django.

Answer (score 13):

Você pode desativar o localize em apenas um valor:

```python
{% load l10n %}
{{ value|unlocalize }}
```

Ou pode desativar em algum trecho do template:

```python
{% load l10n %}
{% localize off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

Fonte: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia usar o

```python
def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

OU

```python
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

E usar a própria classe como string.
Não é a maneira ideal, mas funcionaria.

```
{{ form.instance }}
```

Sobre o Admin, é possível criar Templates customizados se necessário, mas imagino que não seja necessário, o Django deve montar os formulários e funcionar corretamente mesmo com a internacionalização ativada.

Comment: Então o `{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}{{ original.pk }}` acima estar renderizando o URL como `<a href="admin/auth/user/25.263">` pode ser considerado um bug?

Comment: O que vc está fazendo ali é renderizar a id no HTML, num template seu, onde a localização fica ativada, se você está criando links para o admin manualmente em algum template imagino que precise usar o filtro |safe. Eu nunca usei links para urls do Django admin usando a url tag, mas imagino que deva ser possível passar os parâmetros de dentro da tag não? algo como
`{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' original.id %}`

Comment: Não, meu amigo, isso é código do Django! Mas deixe para lá, nas versões mais novas, isso já foi corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode evitar essa formatação numérica utilizando o template tag `safe`:

Entrada:

```
data-id="{{ form.instance.id|safe }}"
```

Saída:

```
data-id="1234"
```

Referência: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Só não entendi o motivo de você estar tendo problemas no admin. No primeiro momento parece que você está customizando. Em seguida diz que o problema ocorre como se não estivesse alterando nada no template do admin.

Comment: A pergunta já menciona a solução com `|safe` ou `|unlocalize`. O problema acontece em todos os lugares onde se renderiza ID em urls, e um desses lugares é o admin (onde eu não quero sobrescrever só para corrigir isso).